Possibly false statement of Exercise 5.16 of Atiyah and Macdonald
Question is originated from this post of mine. Following is statement of Noether normalization lemma given in Atiyah and Macdonald:

Let $k$ be an infinite field and let $A \neq 0$ be a finitely generated $k$-algebra. Then there exist elements $y_1,…,y_r\in A$ which are algebraically independent over $k$ and such that $A$ is integral over $k[y_1,…,y_r]$.

We can easily prove it. For sake of completeness, I am writing proof: Renumber $x_i$ so that $x_1, \dots , x_r$ are independent over $k$ and $x_{r+1}, \dots , x_n$ are dependent over $k$. Base case $n=0$ is trivial. In inductive step, if $r=n$ we’re done. If $r\lt n$, then $x_n$ is dependent over $k$. Then $\exists 0\neq f\in k[X]$ such that $f(x_n)=\sum_{i=0}^ma_ix_n^i=0$. Multiply by $a_m^{-1}$, we have $x_n$ is integral over $k$, therefore over $k[x_1,…,x_{n-1}]$. Now apply inductive hypothesis to finish proof.
Though above is not the intended proof. To avoid above bogus proof, I think, we need to impose condition like $k[y_1,…,y_r]\cong k[T_1,…,T_r]$ (here $T_i$’s are indeterminate) or $y_i$ is indeterminate over $k[y_1,…,y_{i-1}]$ for all $1\leq i\leq r$, which will imply $k[y_1,…,y_r]\cong$ polynomial ring in $r$ variable. Under these condition, bogus proof fails at inductive step $n=r$. Am I correct in my assessment?

You don't need to impose $k[y_1, \ldots, y_r] \cong k[T_1, \ldots, T_r]$: This follows directly from the fact that the $y_i$ are algebraically independent.

@BenSteffan it is given that $y_i$ are algebraically independent over $k$. I have seen version where it is written $y_1,…,y_r$ are algebraically independent elements of $A$, without mentioning over which fields.

@user264745 What do you think it means to say $y_1, \ldots, y_r$ are alebraically independent over $k$? (Your proof seems confused on this note)

@user264745 I don't follow. The $y_i$ are elements of $A$ and so can't be independent over $A$. The $y_i$ being independent over $k$ is equivalent to $k[y_1, \ldots, y_r] \cong k[T_1, \ldots, T_r]$. If this is unclear to you you should prove it; it's not difficult. Also please proofread your proof: I suppose the $x_i$ should be $y_i$, and also the indices are incompatible with the problem statement.

@BrianMoehring each $y_i$ is independent over $k$.

@user264745 No. Please revisit the definition.

@BenSteffan If we interpret $y_1,…,y_r\in A$ are algebraically independent over $k$ as each $y_i$ is independent over $k$, then $k[y_1,…,y_r]$ is not isomorphic to polynomial ring. For instance, $k[x^2,xy,y^2]\subseteq k[x,y]$ is not isomorphic to polynomial ring. Can you please provide link to the definition that you are referring to?

"Each is independent over $k$" doesn't encompass the definition.  Independence is a property of the sequence, and it can't be simplified to a property on each element individually. (This is like saying a sequence of vectors are linearly independent if each vector is nonzero: it's just not how the definition works)

The Wikipedia article for Algebraic Independence has a definition.  I also assume Atiyah/Macdonald has a definition, but my copy is unavailable right now.  The definition I prefer is "the evaluation homomorphism $k[T_1, \ldots T_r] \to A$ taking $T_i \mapsto y_i$ has a trivial kernel."

@BrianMoehring ok my bad. Thank you for the answer. I used my caveman definition of algebraic and transcendental extension I learned from field theory.
